# NameError: "linear regression" is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-regression

Here is a code snippet where I am applying Linear regression using Pytorch. I face a NameError, that says name "linear regression" not defined. Kindly help in rectifying it.

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

x_data=Variable(torch.Tensor([[10.0],[9.0],[3.0],[2.0]]))
y_data=Variable(torch.Tensor([[90.0],[80.0],[50.0],[30.0]]))

class LinearRegression(torch.nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super(LinearRegression,self). __init__ ()
    self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)

  def forward(self, x):
    y_pred = self.linear(x)
    return y_pred

  model = LinearRegression()
```

Comment: Is `model = LinearRegression()` supposed to be indented to be *part of the class*!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model = LinearRegression()` should be outside class

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

x_data=Variable(torch.Tensor([[10.0],[9.0],[3.0],[2.0]]))
y_data=Variable(torch.Tensor([[90.0],[80.0],[50.0],[30.0]]))

class LinearRegression(torch.nn.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    super(LinearRegression,self). __init__ ()
    self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)

  def forward(self, x):
    y_pred = self.linear(x)
    return y_pred

model = LinearRegression()
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Upvoted for speed of correct answer.